# Advisorship, advisorment or advice?

Tags: word-choice

Here are my sentence:

> The discipline of my dissertation is potions under the _____ of PhD Severus Snape.

What should I put in the blank? I think it should be *advisorship*, but somebody tells me it should be *advisorment*, another one thinks it should simply be *advice*. Dictionaries don't define *advisorship* or *advisorment*, but I think there are a situation that these words are required.

Comment: You may want to think of: supervision

Comment: Supervision is for high school students

Comment: Never heard of that, and in fact I have found many dissertations published with the word supervision used. However, if what you say is true it will be a surprise for me and I'll have learned something new! I'll google around now

Comment: If what you say is true it will be a surprise for me and I'll have learned something new, too =)). Can you show me an example of using *supervision* for dissertation?

Comment: If google up this "supervision of graduate students", you'll get some results. One of these results is this link: [Handbook of Graduate Supervision - Graduate Studies](https://www.grad.ubc.ca/handbook-graduate-supervision/handbook-graduate-supervision)

Comment: Wow, new thing to learn. Now I know that university supervisor is advisor.

Comment: I'm not sure what you meant to say with the word "potions", but I'm sure that's not the right word.

Comment: @BenKovitz: why not? See [this](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Potions_(class))

Comment: Ah, I stand corrected. I had skipped the end of your sentence, and didn't realize this was a Harry Potter reference. I was (foolishly) worried that you might be putting this sentence into your own Ph.D. dissertation!

Comment: @BenKovitz Well, I work for Who-must-not-be-named ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That depends on what you're trying to say, although I suspect that *advisorship* is your best choice.

Avoid *advisorment*. The *-ment* suffix is usually used with a verb, to create a noun that represents the action itself, or the result of the action: *move* → *movement*, *pave* → *pavement*. *Advisor* is a noun itself, so adding *-ment* doesn't really create a useful word.

*Advice* suggests that Prof. Snape's involvement in your dissertation may have been limited to suggesting a possible topic for it, which you followed. You could say the same thing about your roommate. I assume that's not what you mean.

If you are trying to say that Prof. Snape is acting in his capacity as advisor to provide guidance as you write your dissertation, then *advisorship*—which uses the *-ship* suffix to indicate a position, office, or duty—is your best bet.

Comment: In the question's comments, learner shows that we can also use *supervision*.

Comment: In the US in my field, and I think the humanities generally, although the professor-in-charge is referred to as the dissertation *advisor*, what he does is *direct* the dissertation, and the dissertator acts under his *direction*.

Comment: There's also "advisement" as a possible word, although I agree with StoneyB.